# Completely destroy all traces of an object in Perl

Tags: perl, oop, reference, destroy

I am writing a Perl script that gets data from a changing outside source.  As data is added or removed from this outside source I would like the data structures in my Perl script to mirror the changes.  I was able to do this by creating objects that store the data in a similar fashion and synchronizing the data in those objects whenever I try to access the data in my Perl script.

This works great, and gets any new data that is added to this external source; however a problem arises when any data is removed.  If any data is removed I want all existing references to it in my Perl script to be destroyed as well so the user can no longer attempt to access the data without raising an error.

---

The only way I could think of was to undefine the internal reference to the data as soon as it is determined that the data no longer exists.  It appears, however; that when a reference is undefined it doesn't remove the data stored in the location of the reference, it only deletes the data from the variable that holds the reference.

---

Here is a test script demonstrating my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

####################################################################################################
# Package to create an object
package Object;

use Moose;

# Define attributes
has 'name' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1);

####################################################################################################
# Package to test with
package test;

# Create an object
my $object1 = Object->new('name' => 'Test Object');
print 'OBJECT1 NAME: '.$object1->name()."\n";

# Create another reference to the object
my $object2 = $object1;

# Print the name
print 'OBJECT2 NAME: '.$object2->name()."\n";

# Print both references
print "\n";
print "OBJ  : $object1\n";
print "OBJ2 : $object2\n";
print "\n";

# Undefine the reference to object2
undef $object2;

# Try to print both names
print 'OBJECT1 NAME: '.$object1->name()."\n";
print 'OBJECT2 NAME: '.$object2->name()."\n";
```

Output:
[image: Script Output]

---

> ***How can I completely destroy all traces of an object so that any attempt to access it's data will result in an error?***

---

***EDIT:***

Here is a different example that may explain better what I am trying to achieve.

Say I have a file object:

`my $file = File->new();`

Now I want to get the text in that file

`my $text = $file->text();`

Now I get it again (for some unknown reason)

`my $text2 = $file->text();`

I want to be able to modify `$text` and have it directly effect the contents of `$text2` as well as change the actual `text` attribute of the file.

I'm basically trying to tie the variables together so if one changes they all change. Also if one is deleted they would all be deleted.

This would also mean if the `text` attribute is changed, `$text1` and `$text2` would also change with it to reflect the new value.

Could this be done using an alias of some sort?

Comment: So you want `$object1` to become `undef` after you type `undef $object2` ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: See also [How do you explicitly destroy an object in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772220/how-do-you-explicitly-destroy-an-object-in-perl)

Comment: Yeah I looked at that first, that tells you how to do the undef, but not how to get rid of every instance of it.

Comment: Do you actually need to physically erase the object from memory, or could you simply do with adding a field like `is_deleted` to the object? Such that each time you try to access the object, you could check if it still is valid.

Comment: That may work, but it would ultimately be cleaner if I could keep the Perl data structure identical to the external data structure.

Comment: As tjd mentioned, this sort of action at a distance is generally a bad thing. It makes your code hard to maintain and hard to use. Generally you change an object with a setter method, so instead of changing `$text` you would do `$file->text('foo');`. Can you explain in more detail why you want to do it this way?

Comment: You're right @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, that comment made me realize that is not the exact functionality I am really looking for.  I will try and pull out the "real" problem in this question and post a more concise question that will hopefully get my point across better.  I will post the link to it in the comments here.

Comment: Here is the link to a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856188/link-a-variable-to-a-class-attribute-in-perl). Hopefully this will help narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 2):

Perl uses reference counting to "retire" data.

What your program is doing is as follows:

1. Create an object and assign a reference to `$object1`
2. Copy that reference to `$object2` and increment the object's reference count
3. Change the value of `$object2` and decrement the object's reference count.

In the end you still have a hold of the object via `$object1` and it's reference count will not drop to below 1 while you keep a hold of it.  Technically as your program shuts down the `$object1` variable will be destroyed as it goes out of scope, at which the object's reference count will drop to 0 and perl will look for and try to call it's `DESTROY` method.

If you truly want to "see" an item destroyed you may want to look into defining a `DESTROY` method that prints out a message upon object destruction.  This way you can "let go" of your last reference and still see it's destruction.

Comment: Okay, that explains what is happening, but how can I force Perl to eliminate both `$object1` and `$object2` simultaneously?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Action at a distance is not generally considered desirable.  but instead of *copying* your reference, I suppose you could create `$object2` as an *alias* to `$object1`.

Comment: I believe aliases are what I am looking for.  It looks like this can be done using a `typeglob` (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=976523). I haven't quite wrapped my head around `typeglobs` and how they work yet though.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 typeglobs are not recommended.  They rely on Global/Package variables.  (We're back to the idea of action at a distance.)  Look to CPAN for Lexical solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't free an object that's still being used. Have the object itself keep track of whether it's still valid or not.

```
sub new { 
   my ($class, $data) = @_;
   my $self = bless({}, $class);
   $self->{valid} = 1;
   $self->{data} = $data;
   return $self;
}

sub delete {
   my $self = shift;
   undef(%$self);
}

sub data {
   my $self = shift;
   croak("Invalid object") if !$self->{valid};
   $self->{data} = $_[0] if @_;
   return $self->{data};
}
```

Example:

```
my $o1 = Class->new('big_complex_data');
my $o2 = $o1;

say $o1->data();
say $o2->data();

$o1->delete();
say $o2->name();
```

Output:

```
big_complex_data
big_complex_data
Invalid object at a.pl line 39.
```

Comment: That would work great if these objects only had one attribute, but they can have many different attributes, and some of those attributes may still be valid.  I know my example above doesn't account for this since I delete the whole object, but in reality I have a very complex data structure where only small sections may become invalid and if they are invalid I would like to remove them so they cannot be accessed again without crashing the program.  I only want it to crash if the user explicitly attempts to retrieve invalid data.

Comment: Tip: If it helps, `delete` can record the stack frame in order to include it in the error message thrown when accessing an invalid object.

Comment: That's not a problem. Your attribute builder would build all attributes to check whether the object is valid.

Comment: Also with such large complex objects just changing a flag would leave the object in memory.  As the program continued to run these "deleted" objects would build up causing the program to consume more memory and would act like a memory leak.

Comment: First of all, that's seems unlikely. It will only stay in memory as long as you're still using it. Why do you keep using objects longer you've deleted them? Second, why do you have multiple copies of such large data structures? Your objects should all refer to the same data structure. Not only would that save memory, it would completely eliminate this problem.

Comment: They are the same data structure, but if pieces of it become invalid and they are just flagged as invalid they would remain in memory.  Then as new data came into the structure the size would continue to grow.  New data would be able to keep coming in causing the structure to grow, but old data would never completely be purged until the script was terminated.

Comment: Re "They are the same data structure", What does that mean?

Comment: But what you are doing isn't actually deleting it, it is just flagging the object as invalid. I think I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: Arg. In the comments, you asked a different question, to which I gave a different answer. If you have multiple objects with copies of the data as you said in your question, you'll have to use something like in my answer. If on the other hand you have a single large structure accessed by all the objects, just delete from the structure.

Comment: Let me modify my question. I will come up with a different scenario.

Comment: The update to your question didn't change anything. It just repeats the rest of the question, but with an attribute named `text` instead of `name`. You can't free an object that's still being used.