# Link a variable to a class attribute in Perl

Tags: perl, oop, attributes

This question was born out of another ([Completely destroy all traces of an object in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841484/completely-destroy-all-traces-of-an-object-in-perl/31841647#comment51614865_31841647)).  After seeing some of the comments I believe I have narrowed the problem down to the "real" issue.

I'm looking for a simple way to link a variable to a class attribute in Perl so that whenever the attribute is modified, the variable will be automatically updated.

ex (some pseudo code):

```
# Create a file object
my $file = File->new();

# Get the text
my $text = $file->text();

# prints 'hello'
print $text;

# Set the text
$file->text('goodbye');

# prints 'goodbye'
print $text;
```

Also I want the `$text` variable to be read only so that you cannot inadvertently modify the `text` attribute of the file.

Comment: Also I would prefer a solution that doesn't require installing any modules from CPAN.  With the security restrictions here we can't download any modules.  I would need to request the module, get it approved, and wait for an IT tech to come and install it.  Then if anyone else here wanted to use my module they would need to request it as well and wait for it to be installed.  It's just a huge hassle.

Comment: Have you looked into tied variables - http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html ?

Comment: Have a look at the source code of [`Lexical::Alias`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lexical::Alias) and [`Readonly`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Readonly)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into both of those options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [tie](http://p3rl.org/tie):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

{   package File;

    sub new {
        bless ['hello'], shift
    }

    sub text {
        my $self = shift;
        if (@_) {
            $self->[0] = shift;
        } else {
            return $self->[0]
        }
    }
}

{   package FileVar;
    use Tie::Scalar;
    use parent qw( -norequire Tie::StdScalar );

    sub TIESCALAR {
        my ($class, $obj) = @_;
        bless \$obj, $class
    }

    sub FETCH {
        my $self = shift;
        ${$self}->text()
    }

    sub STORE {
        die 'Read only!';

        # Or, do you want to change the object by changing the var, too?
        my ($self, $value) = @_;
        ${$self}->text($value);
    }

}

my $file = 'File'->new();
tie my $text, 'FileVar', $file;
say $text;
$file->text('goodbye');
say $text;

# Die or change the object:
$text = 'Magic!';
say $file->text;
```

Comment: Thanks @choroba, That is very close to what I am looking for.  The one issue with it is that this class will be used by people who may not know how "tie" works.  Basically I want it to hide the "tying" from the user by returning the tied variable directly from the `$file->text()` accessor.  I'm sure I could figure it out using your code as an example but it may take me a little bit since I am quite unfamiliar with tying variables myself.

Comment: Also I will need a way to make this generic so it will work on all attributes of the `$file` object (There will be more than just text).  I obviously don't want to write a separate package for every attribute.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 maybe this is the right time to edjucate your peers on how to work with objects. No time like the present. :)

Comment: Ha! I agree, but we're talking about a place that still uses FORTRAN.  It may be a more daunting task than you think!

Comment: Also is there a way to incorporate this directly into the `File` package?  I feel like that would be cleaner than having to create a separate package to tie `File` attributes.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: I might not be available once the magic bites them. Educate yourself, educate them, study [perltie](http://p3rl.org/perltie)
and [overload](http://p3rl.org/overload).

Comment: I will thanks! Also what is this line for? `use parent qw( -norequire Tie::StdScalar );` it still works without it.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: It supplies undeclared standard subs. For a scalar, only the three used here are needed, so it can be skipped.